# Shuffle a collection of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a bunch of corresponding training data for a model. I'm trying to randomize their orders.

What I thought would work would be this:

```
rand_inds = np.arange(len(d_bundle))
np.random.shuffle(rand_inds)

for i in [d_bundle, d2_bundle, d_location_bundle, output_bundle]:
    i = i[rand_inds]
```

However, this doesn't actually modify the stuffs inside of the list. I'd have to do it all manually. If I don't want to do it manually, it seems I could just make another array like `c = [d_bundle, d2_bundle, d_location_bundle, output_bundle]` and then run through the loop. Then I'd just unpack the bundles into `c`. However, this would use up more memory than needed right?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Assigning `i=i[rand_inds]` inside a loop over `i` is likely to cause a massive amount of trouble.

Comment: Is it your intent to have the same random order for each array?

Comment: Yup. I want them to swap with the same indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can do this by indexing as:

```
np.array(ll)[:, rand_inds]
```

This code will modify all the stuffs, and will make their types the same e.g. if we have *float64* and *float32*, it will convert one of the types to the another one. You can convert the resulted NumPy array to list by add `.tolist()` at the end of that.

- Using NumPy arrays and indexing, usually, will consume less memory and is much faster than common loops.

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by splitting up the loop:

```
import numpy as np

# generate test lists. These are your "d_bundle", etc.
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
l2 = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
l3 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
ll = [l1, l2, l3]  # This is your list of lists

rand_inds = np.arange(len(l1)) # initial, as-is ordering.
np.random.shuffle(rand_inds)   # shuffle rand_inds

for i in range(len(ll)):   # Handle each sublist separately
    l = ll[i]              # Select the sublist to modify
    newl = list(l)         # This reserves memory so we have separate input and output sublists
    for j in range(len(newl)):  # Shuffle the sublist
        newl[j] = l[rand_inds[j]]
    ll[i] = list(newl)     # Put the new sublist in the list of lists

l1, l2, l3 = tuple(ll)     # write the variables back to the original names. Order must match the original `ll` assignment.
```

I used a lot of `list()` calls to be very clear about when I wanted to deal with list contents rather than modifying things in-place.  This is probably not the most memory-efficient solution, but it should work.

Comment: I guess it does work. The problem is that the code is longer than if I just shuffled the arrays manually which I did. If it creates new lists, I'm fairly certain that that causes new memory to be used up.